# Net group output sorting

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, command-line, active-directory

The command `net group "Groupname" /domain > c:\temp\users.txt` will generate the following output in the text file.

```
Group name     GroupABC
Comment        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Members

--------------------------------------------------------------------
MemberA                  MemberB                  MemberC 
MemberD                  MemberE                  MemberF 
MemberG                  MemberH                  MemberI
The command completed successfully.
```

I'd need to get rid of the unnecessary header and comment at the end of the file and simply have the output in an ordered list as follows:

```
MemberA
MemberB
MemberC
MemberD
MemberE
MemberF
...
```

Is there an easy way to do this without having to output to the file and remove the header manually? Your help with the sorting and removal of unnecessary spacing is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why have you tagged `[powershell]` but you're not using `Get-ADGroupMember` ?

Comment: Argh, I was hoping the `net` command is intelligent enough to adapt its multi-column output to a single-column one in case the console window is made more narrow, but no luck, it seems that `net` always uses three 25 characters wide columns. So I suggest to not use `for /F` (and split at spaces which might also occur in some names), but to split the lines into pieces of 25 characters (by [sub-string expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) and remove trailing spaces afterwards...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion aschipfl. I'm new to this, so it would really help if you could provide some sample sub-string expansion code. Thanks!

Comment: StackOverflow is still not a coding service. We are more than willing to help but you need to show some effort so that we can build on whatever solution you were trying to work on. Do you have _any_ attempt of a solution?

Comment: I strongly suggest to move away from `net.exe` and batch files for AD group management. Use PowerShell with the `ActiveDirectory` module or a `DirectorySearcher` object (if you don't have the module available). Or use VBScript (e.g. with my [`ADQuery`](http://sdb.planetcobalt.net/adquery.shtml) class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q47813094.txt"
:: remove variables starting $
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="
SET "body="
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 REM detect last line
 IF "%%a"=="The command completed successfully." SET "body="
 IF DEFINED body FOR %%m IN (%%a) DO SET "$%%m=%%m"
 REM detect start-of-body
 IF "%%a"=="--------------------------------------------------------------------" SET "body=y"
)
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a IN ('set $') DO ECHO %%b
GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q47813094.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Naturally, you could replace `"filename"` with `'your command'` and remove the `usebackq` option to process the command directly.

Each line is processed as `%%a`. AT first, `body` is undefined, so setting of `$...` is skipped. When the line of dashes is found, `body` is set to `Y` (any non-empty value will do) and so on subsequent lines each member is assigned to `%%m` and the variable `$%%m` set to the member-name found. On the last line, the end-of-report is detected, which sets `body` to *nothing* hence it one again becomes undefined.

Then use `set` on variables starting `$` which will conveniently return the list in alphabetical order.

---

To replace original file:

(FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a IN ('set $') DO ECHO %%b)>"%filename1%"

The enclosing parentheses cause the redirector to gather the displayed output and produce a new file. If there is an existing file, that file will be replaced.

Comment: Thanks Magoo, the script seems to work and sorts users in alphabetical order. However, the text file that is used as input is not modified. Is there a way to overwrite the original .txt?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `net` always uses three 25 characters wide columns. So I wrote a small script that does not use `for /F` to split the lines at <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> which might also occur in some names, but to split the lines into pieces of 25 characters by [sub-string expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) and remove trailing spaces afterwards:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_GROUP=GroupName" & rem // (define the group name here)
set "_SPACES=                " & rem // (16 spaces)

rem // Initialise variables:
set "LINE=" & set "FLAG="
rem // Loop through all (non-empty) output lines of `net group`:
for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ('net group "%_GROUP%" /DOMAIN') do (
    rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid loss of or trouble with `!`:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Query state of flag:
    if defined FLAG (
        rem // Split the line string into three 25-character strings:
        for /L %%P in (0,25,50) do (
            rem // Extract a single column item (a 25-character string):
            set "COL=!LINE:~%%P,25!"
            rem // Split off trailing space characters:
            for %%S in (16 8 4 2 1) do (
                if defined COL (
                    if "!COL:~-%%S!"=="!_SPACES:~,%%S!" (
                        set "COL=!COL:~,-%%S!"
                    )
                )
            )
            rem // Return non-empty right-trimmed column item:
            if defined COL echo(!COL!
        )
    )
    rem // Set flag in case last header line is encountered (`-` only):
    if "!LINE:-=!"=="" (endlocal & set "FLAG=#") else endlocal
    rem /* Store currently read line to be processed in the next loop iteration;
    rem    this lets the last line be ignored, which is just a success message: */
    set "LINE=%%L"
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

This approach allows even <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> to appear in the returned names, and it does not have any problems with special characters (like `^`, `%`, `!`, `&`, `"`, `(`, `)`, `<`, `>`, `|`).